# Unable to Upsert Salesforce Object from Node Js

Tags: node.js, salesforce, jsforce

I am trying to do a Upsert operation on a Salesforce Object named "Lead" from a node js. While sending the data i am getting the below error response back from Salesforce

```
{
    "success": false,
    "errors": [
        {
            "statusCode": "METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED",
            "message": "HTTP Method 'PATCH' not allowed. Allowed are GET,HEAD,POST"
        }
    ]
}
```

Strange part is that the same upsert functionality is working fine for other Salesforce object but I am getting only for "Lead" object.  Please help to share your inputs if someone has a solution.

Thank you for all your support.

Thanks,
Janakiram.

Answer (score 0):

does your user have Profile (or permission set) with "Create" and "Edit" right on Leads? What url are you calling? Does your Lead object have an external id field & your user can see/edit it?

Comment: Yes my user has the admin access on all objects of Salesforce. Yes i have external Id field. Actually Upsert meaning it has to Create or Update based on External Id field so in my case i am passing empty value to my external Id as it need to create the record in Salesforce but when i am passing the existing external Id value in the message it was updating the data in Salesforce. So i am stuck while creating the record with an empty external Id field value. Please help if you have any solution for this

Comment: Have you tried straight insert (POST to `/services/data/v53.0/sobjects/Lead/`, not PATCH)? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_create.htm. If it doesn't work but profile permissions all look good try editing your user (not Profile, User!) and give yourself a "Marketing User" checkbox. It shouldn't be needed for Leads, from what I remember it matters only in Campaigns but been a while since I did it, maybe something changed.

Comment: This is the Url which i am using to post my data towards Salesforce.
https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/33.0

Comment: You have to make up your mind, are you using SOAP API (https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/06/salesforce-soap-api-sample-wsdls, scroll to "create") or REST (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_create.htm). From what I remember in SOAP it's always a POST, even for upsert. You shown a JSON error message so I thought you're using the REST API

Comment: Thank for your response I have one query why do i have an issue with this Object Type towards Salesforce. I am not encountering any issues with the other Objects. Also i would like to let you know that i have create a REST API service which would use JSForce node module to perform the different operation on Salesforce. Do I need to change the URL? please advise.

Comment: Looks like jsforce can use either SOAP or REST, you decide? https://jsforce.github.io/document/ You'll need to post some code for us to answer better, some minimal reproducible example. REST API respects object and field-level permissions, I think SOAP is bit more relaxed. If it's just about 1 sobject type - sounds like profile issues. It's standard Lead, right? not something coming from a managed package where you might not have a license?

Comment: Yes I am followed the same jsforce.github.io/document for posting the data towards Salesforce. As i do see constraints on number of character i cannot able to post the code here.

Comment: Sorry for not updating after the fix. I have done a straight insert so it worked. This issue was closed.